# Converting 128 bit int for row key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, type-conversion

If I wish to have a comparable 128 bit integer equivalent as a row key in Cassandra, what data type is the most efficient to process this? ASCII using the full 8-bit range?

I need to be able to select row slices and ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just use the raw byte[] representation of the int and avoid any conversion; Comments above from le douard withstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Row keys are not compared if you use Random Partitioner (the piece that determine how the keys get distributed around the cluster).
If you want to compare row keys use a Order Preserving partitioner ... but that will surely lead to an unbalanced  cluster and crashes.

Column names get compared though, with other column names inside the same row.

So my advise is Bucket your columns into number intervals and insert your columns with LongType column name.

Answer (score 1):

Raw byte[] comparison is not going to sort columns in numerical order.  If that's what you want you should use varint (CQL) / IntegerType (Thrift)

Comment: What is the size limit of this type?

Comment: Also, I am only talking about keys.

Comment: I'm confused: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family says that varint can be used in comparators or validators. Why wouldn't the cols be sorted with this type?

Comment: @IanC There is no size limit. I think jbellis might have just been addressing the sorting issue if you were to use raw byte arrays for column names, but if you're only using them for row keys, raw byte arrays are fine, because the sorting does not matter.

Comment: @TylerHobbs thanks. Ah, so "BytesType" cannot be validated hence sorted.

Comment: @TylerHobbs I will need to use OP with integer row keys (the data will be randomized another way). Will I be able to do row key range queries and <=> with type varint?

Comment: @IanC Yes, you'll be able to do range queries with proper sorting, however, I strongly discourage you from using an order preserving partitioner. See this: http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/cassandra-randompartitioner-vs-orderpreservingpartitioner/

Comment: @TylerHobbs I've worked out how to use RP for what I want. However, I'm still stuck on what types can and cannot be sorted. Depending on what blog I read, the picture changes.

Comment: @IanC all of the types have a natural sorting order, it's just a different way of interpreting the same set of raw bytes. If you use BytesType for the comparator, your columns will still be sorted, they will just be sorted in the same way that java sorts byte arrays, which is a different order than you would get if the column names were interpreted as integers.

Comment: Ok, BytesType will be a binary sort, not numeric. I get it. Thank much!